# SQL table joins query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate responses for a questionnaire system. I want to show the result in one table (the question, options, number of responses). I wrote a query which works just fine however, it doesn't display all the options and if there are no responses for them.

My query

```
SELECT       R.QuestionID, Q.QuestionName, A.OptionName, COUNT(R.OptionID) AS Responses, A.OptionID
FROM            Response AS R 
INNER JOIN
                     Question AS Q ON Q.QuestionID = R.QuestionID 
INNER JOIN
                     Option AS A ON R.OptionID = A.OptionID
WHERE        (R.QuestionnaireID = 122)
GROUP BY R.QuestionID, Q.QuestionName, A.OptionName,  R.OptionID, A.OptionID
```

**database structure**:

- Questionnaire (questionnaireID PK, questionnaireName)
- Question (questionID PK, questionnaireID FK, questionnaireName)
- Option (OptionID PK, questionID FK, optionName)
- Response (ResponseID PK, questionnaireID FK, questionID FK, value)

**Table definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questionnaire] (
    [QuestionnaireID]          INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionnaireName]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionnaireID] ASC),
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionID]          INT    IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionnaireID]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [QuestionName]        NVARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Question_Questionnaire] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionnaireID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Questionnaire] ([QuestionnaireID])
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Option] (
    [OptionID]   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] INT             NOT NULL,
    [OptionName] NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OptionID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Option_Question] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionID])
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Response] (
    [ResponseID]      INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionnaireID] INT             NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [Val]             NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [OptionID]        INT             NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ResponseID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Response_Option] FOREIGN KEY ([OptionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Option] ([OptionID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Response_Question] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Response_Questionnaire] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionnaireID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Questionnaire] ([QuestionnaireID])
);
```

**Current data:**

```
insert into questionnaire values ('ASP.NET questionnaire');
insert into questionnaire values('TEST questionnaire');

insert into question values (2, 'rate our services');
insert into question values (2, 'On scale from 1 to 5, how much youre sleepy?');
insert into question values (2, 'how are you today');

insert into [Option] values (1, 'good');
insert into [Option] values (1, 'bad');
insert into [Option] values (1, 'medium');

insert into [Option] values(2, '1');
insert into [Option] values(2, '2');
insert into [Option] values(2, '3');
insert into [Option] values(2, '4');
insert into [Option] values(2, '5');

insert into [option] values (3, 'fine');
insert into [option] values (3, 'great');
insert into [option] values (3, 'not bad');
insert into [option] values (3, 'bad');

insert into response values(2, 1, 'good', 1);
insert into response values(2, 1, 'good', 1);
insert into response values(2, 1, 'bad', 2);
insert into response values(2, 1, 'good', 1);

insert into response values(2, 2, '1', 4);
insert into response values(2, 2, '3', 3);
insert into response values(2, 2, '4', 5);
insert into response values(2, 2, '5', 8);
```

**Desired output**

[image: Output]

**SQL Fiddle**

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/084d0/3)

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: Please share sample data in the three tables and the desired result based on the sample data.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data and for the output, you could check the table in the picture I uploaded. I'm hoping to show the question, option and the number of people who chose the same option. This can be done by using the response table and without table joins, however I don't want to show the IDs as it won't be easy to read by the user..

Comment: @ElSS did you understand my answer or should I explain it?

Comment: An explanation would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, if you want to `display all the options and if there are no responses for them` like

**EDIT**

I have updated the answer based on your SQL fiddle. It works in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4acf0/14) and gives you your desired output.

```
SELECT     Q.QuestionName AS Question, 
           A.OptionName AS [Option], 
           COUNT(R.OptionID) AS Responses
FROM         Question AS Q 
INNER JOIN
      [Option] AS A ON A.questionID = Q.questionID 
LEFT JOIN
     Response AS R  ON Q.QuestionID = R.QuestionID  AND R.OptionId=A.Optionid

WHERE        (Q.QuestionnaireID = 2)
GROUP BY Q.QuestionID, Q.QuestionName, A.OptionName
ORDER BY Q.QuestionName,A.OptionName
```

Comment: It returns the same result as my query.

Comment: It gives value of 1 to options with zero responses for some reason.  I played around with it  but still.. it doesn't show null when there are no responses.

Comment: So the query shows each question's options even with zero responses but assigns 1 to options with zero responses. am I right?

Comment: Ah well.. it still assigns value of 1 to options with no responses. perhaps what I'm trying to do is being done using the wrong way or it's impossible. Will figure out a workaround. Thanks anyway, friend.

Comment: It should work now try it for a last time it is definitely possible. It is always good at the tables and sample data to [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and ask people to answer this way your question and data will be very clear

Comment: Hehe I spent about 6 hours butt hurt trying to figure this out. It's about time to give up and try another way of doing it. But Alright my friend, I'll give it one more shot. gonna build the database in fiddle now.

Comment: Here's [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/084d0/3). Not sure how it exactly works, but I created it.

Answer (score 3):

It could be something to do with your Inner joins. an Inner join produces only the set of records that match in both Table A and Table B.

Reviewing this might be of help http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I have read this article plenty of times and tried everything, yet I get the same result as my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    R.QuestionID, isnull(Q.QuestionName, ''), isnull(A.OptionName, ''), 
    sum(case when A.OptionID is not null then 1 else 0 end) ResponsesCount
from Response R 
left join Question Q on
    R.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
left join [Option] A on 
    R.OptionID = A.OptionID
where
    R.QuestionnaireID = 122
group by
    R.QuestionID, isnull(Q.QuestionName, ''), 
    isnull(A.OptionName, ''), R.OptionID
```

Here, as you see, I replace inner join to left join to take into consideration not responded options.
Also I changed `count` logic - we need to count only not null ID's (so I used `case` statement in `sum`). And finally I wrapped all 'may be null columns' (from left-joined tables) into `isnull` func.

Comment: It returns the same result as my query.